# How to catch antlr parser or lexer errors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, frontend, frameworks, antlr

So I want to make a custom frontend framework called NLweb, its something basic with just variables, functions and nested jsx.

Now I want to handle parsing or lexing errors in my compile function (or in my visitor, but I guess that's not possible because the parsing/lexing errors get thrown before entering my custom visitor)...
So can anyone tell me how I catch these kinds of errors?

```
  console.error
    line 3:4 missing ';' at '<EOF>'

      203 |
      204 |             this.state = 38;
    > 205 |             this.match(NLwebParser.T__2);
          |                  ^
      206 |         } catch (re) {
      207 |             if(re instanceof antlr4.error.RecognitionException) {
      208 |                     localctx.exception = re;

      at ConsoleErrorListener.syntaxError (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/error/ErrorListener.js:44:17)
      at node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/error/ErrorListener.js:65:35
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/error/ErrorListener.js:65:24)
      at NLwebParser.notifyErrorListeners (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/Parser.js:356:12)
      at DefaultErrorStrategy.reportMissingToken (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/error/ErrorStrategy.js:375:20)
      at DefaultErrorStrategy.singleTokenInsertion (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/error/ErrorStrategy.js:472:18)
      at DefaultErrorStrategy.recoverInline (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/error/ErrorStrategy.js:438:18)
      at NLwebParser.match (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/Parser.js:120:25)
      at NLwebParser.match [as variable] (src/js/generated/NLwebParser.js:205:15)
      at NLwebParser.variable [as statement] (src/js/generated/NLwebParser.js:142:19)
      at NLwebParser.statement [as compilation] (src/js/generated/NLwebParser.js:111:19)
      at compilation (src/js/index.js:18:32)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/index.test.js:11:32)
```

Here is some context:

My grammar:

```
grammar NLweb;

compilation
    : statement*
    ;

statement
    :   variable
    |   procedure
    |   callProcedure
    |   jsxTag
    ;

variable
    :   'waarde' Identifier '='? (literal)? ';'
    ;


literal
    :   Number
    |   String
    |   Check
    ;

procedure
    :   'procedure' Identifier '=>' parameters? '=>' '(' statement* ');'
    ;


parameters
    :   Identifier (',' Identifier)*
    ;

callProcedure
    :   'start' Identifier '=>' '(' parameters? ');'
    ;

jsxTag
    :   '<' Identifier '>' (text|jsxTag)* '</' Identifier '>'
    ;

text
    :   ~('\r' | '\n' | '<' | '>' )+
    ;

Identifier: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
Number : [0-9]+;
String : [a-zA-Z]+;
Check : 'True' | 'False';
WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

My index.js:

```
import * as antlr from 'antlr4'
import NLwebLexer from './generated/NLwebLexer.js'
import NLwebParser from './generated/NLwebParser.js'
import Visitor from './Visitor'


export function nlWebCompile(input) {
    try {
        const chars = new antlr.InputStream(input)
        const lexer = new NLwebLexer(chars)
        const tokens = new antlr.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        const parser = new NLwebParser(tokens)
        const context = parser.compilation()
        const visitor = new Visitor()
        return visitor.visitCompilation(context)
    }catch (error){
        throw Error('Syntax error')
    }

}
```

One of a few tests (it still passes testing, but the error I provided earlier displays in console still, I guess that's not a good sign either?):

```
// Test to declare variables
test('visitor should return correct type and identifier when declaring a variable', () => {
    const input = `
    waarde testWaarde = 5
    `
    const result = nlWebCompile(input)
    expect(result[0].type).toBe('variable')
    expect(result[0].identifier).toBe('testWaarde')
    expect(result[0].literal.literal).toBe('5')
})
```

And this is some of my visitor:

```
class MyVisitor extends NLwebVisitor {

    visitCompilation(ctx) {
        const statements = ctx.statement()
        const result = []
        for (const statement of statements) {
            result.push(this.visitStatement(statement))
        }
        return result
    }
    visitStatement(ctx) {
        if (ctx.variable()) {
            return this.visitVariable(ctx.variable())
        } else if (ctx.procedure()) {
            return this.visitProcedure(ctx.procedure())
        } else if (ctx.callProcedure()) {
            return this.visitCallProcedure(ctx.callProcedure())
        }else if (ctx.jsxTag()) {
            return this.visitJsxTag(ctx.jsxTag())
        }
    }
    visitVariable(ctx) {
        const identifier = ctx.Identifier().getText()
        const literal = ctx.literal() ? this.visitLiteral(ctx.literal()) : []
        return {
            type : 'variable',
            identifier,
            literal
        }
    }
}
```

If I add an errorListner like this:

```
export function nlWebCompile(input) {
    const chars = new antlr.InputStream(input)
    const lexer = new NLwebLexer(chars)
    const tokens = new antlr.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    const parser = new NLwebParser(tokens)
    parser.buildParseTrees = true
    parser.removeErrorListeners()
    parser.addErrorListener({
        syntaxError: (recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, err) => {
            console.error(`${offendingSymbol} line ${line}, col ${column}: ${msg}`)
        }
    })
    const context = parser.compilation()
    const visitor = new Bezoeker()
    return visitor.visitCompilation(context)
}
```

Before doing that my first 5 tests would succeed, but after adding the errorListner this happens in console, could I catch all errors instead of only the syntaxError:

```
 FAIL  test/index.test.js
  ✓ visitor should return correct type and identifier when declaring a variable (10 ms)
  ✓ visitor should return correct type, identifier, parameters and statements when declaring a procedure (3 ms)
  ✓ visitor should return correct type, identifier, parameters when calling a procedure (2 ms)
  ✕ visitor should return correct type and identifier for JSX statement (4 ms)
  ✓ generator should return correct javascript code (1 ms)
  ✕ generator should return correct javascript code for functions (4 ms)

  ● visitor should return correct type and identifier for JSX statement

    TypeError: d.reportAttemptingFullContext is not a function

      478 |                     this.state = 92; 
      479 |                     this._errHandler.sync(this);
    > 480 |                     _alt = this._interp.adaptivePredict(this._input,10, this._ctx);
          |                                         ^
      481 |             } while ( _alt!=2 && _alt!=antlr4.atn.ATN.INVALID_ALT_NUMBER );
      482 |         } catch (re) {
      483 |             if(re instanceof antlr4.error.RecognitionException) {

      at node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/error/ErrorListener.js:73:35
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at ProxyErrorListener.reportAttemptingFullContext (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/error/ErrorListener.js:73:24)
      at ParserATNSimulator.reportAttemptingFullContext (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/atn/ParserATNSimulator.js:1688:52)
      at ParserATNSimulator.execATN (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/atn/ParserATNSimulator.js:455:22)
      at ParserATNSimulator.adaptivePredict (node_modules/antlr4/src/antlr4/atn/ParserATNSimulator.js:344:30)
      at NLwebParser.adaptivePredict [as text] (src/compiler/js/generated/NLwebParser.js:480:31)
      at NLwebParser.text [as jsxTag] (src/compiler/js/generated/NLwebParser.js:416:27)
      at NLwebParser.jsxTag (src/compiler/js/generated/NLwebParser.js:420:27)
      at NLwebParser.jsxTag [as statement] (src/compiler/js/generated/NLwebParser.js:157:19)
      at NLwebParser.statement [as compilation] (src/compiler/js/generated/NLwebParser.js:111:19)
      at compilation (src/compiler/js/NLwebCompiler.js:23:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/index.test.js:55:32)
```

I tried the try catch block thats still there in my index.js.
I tried try-catch block in my visitCompilation function but still the parser errors came in console.
And I tried to implement a custom errorListener but I want able to succeed.

Comment: I tried adding a custom errorListener like that but it didn't work, I will try again and let you know what happens. @MikeCargal

Comment: I added some more code with the errorlistener, but still won't catch errors like I want. The syntax errors do get printed out correctly though. @MikeCargal

Answer (score 0):

The error listeners are used by ANTLR to report your errors back to whatever wants to know about them.  It’s up to code to call those listeners.  During Lexington and Parsing, ANTLR will handle its own exceptions and report the errors to any error listeners that are attached.  When your visitor is run, that exception handling is not in place.  However, your visitor can use the same error listeners to make note of errors you encounter while visiting; just call the appropriate method on your error listener.

Note: in general, you want to take care with using exceptions for this.  If you just throw an exception when you encounter an error and have a top level try-catch, then the first error you encounter will abort your visit of the tree and you won’t report any subsequent errors.  You’ll probably do better to just call the method on you error listener to add the error directly whenever you encounter it.  (It’s not that exceptions are always the wrong answer, but you need to understand the implications of catching and recovering from that exception)

Comment: Lets assume I will handle errors only in visitor, how do I ignore the errors that my parser gives? And how would I be able to write tests for syntax error output to user?

Comment: Not sure why you would ignore parser errors (you won’t be able to “reproduce” tyhemm from the resulting parse tree), but if you do, you can just remove the error listeners from the Lexer and the Parser.  Re: unit tests… just have attach an error  listener that collects errors into an array and then check that array when you’re done with your visitor.